# Show form errors before opening AJAX modal

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have a form that adds a product to the cart.

The form uses AJAX to open a modal when the form is submitted.

I want to show form errors (if any) before the modal opens and avoid opening it if there are errors.

Here's my form submit element:

```
$form['submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => '::submitAjaxForm'
  ],
  '#attached' => [
    'library' => ['core/drupal.dialog.ajax'],
  ],
];
```

My `submitAjaxForm`:

```
public function submitAjaxForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand(
    $this->t('Product added to cart!'),
    [
      '#theme' => 'some_theme',
    ]
  ));

  return $response;
}
```

And my `submitForm`:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // Add product to cart.
}
```

I have tried by adding this code to the AjaxSubmit but it only shows the error messages once the page has been reloaded.

```
if ($form_state::hasAnyErrors()) {
  foreach ($form_state->getErrors() as $error) {
    $this->messenger()->addError($error);

    $message = [
      '#theme' => 'status_messages',
      '#message_list' => $this->messenger()->messagesByType(MessengerInterface::TYPE_ERROR),
    ];

    $messages = $this->renderer->render($message);

    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#result-message', $messages));
    $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);

    return $response;
  }
}
```

How can I show the errors without having to reload the page?

Answer (score 0):

I see two things that stand out to me:

1) Setting the '#name' attribute on the submit button. You should never do that. I've learned over the days that there is always a better way to do whatever you're trying to do when setting the #name attribute, and setting it causes some wonkiness. This may be why your form is not rebuilding.

2) You are rendering your status messages in a D7 way. Use this instead:

$messages = ['#type' => 'status_messages'];
$response->addCommand(new PrependCommand('#target-div', \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($messages)));
It looks weird, because the messages aren't being retrieved, but by setting the #type to status messages, Drupal will handle the retrieval in the background. This is probably why you are seeing some funkiness with the messages.

Comment: I don't set `#name` on the submit button.